# Defold physics, sluggish

Tags: game-physics, physics, defold

I'm trying to make an object drop like a rock (pretty fast) but it seems to not want to go faster. I have tried increasing the gravity to insane amounts, but it only seems to change the direction.
Sample output

DEBUG:SCRIPT: vmath.vector3(-60, -1.0000000200409e+20, 0)

I have set mass to 999

I have tried toggling with restitution, friction and linear dampening.

Nothing works and I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are experiencing is caused by large objects at a standard physics scale. The [physics documentation](https://defold.com/manuals/physics/#units-used-by-the-physics-engine-simulation) says:

The physics engine simulates Newtonian physics and it is designed to work well with meters, kilograms and seconds (MKS) units. Furthermore, the physics engine is tuned to work well with moving objects of a size in the 0.1 to 10 meters range (static objects can be larger) and by default the engine treats 1 unit (pixel) as 1 meter. This conversion between pixels and meters is convenient on a simulation level, but from a game creation perspective it isn’t very useful. With default settings a collision shape with a size of 200 pixels would be treated as having a size of 200 meters which is well outside of the recommended range, at least for a moving object. In general it is required that the physics simulation is scaled for it to work well with the typical size of objects in a game. The scale of the physics simulation can be changed in game.project via the physics scale setting. Setting this value to for instance 0.02 would mean that 200 pixels would be treated as a 4 meters. Do note that the gravity (also changed in game.project) has to be increased to accommodate for the change in scale.

In your case I'd open game.project and adjust the physics scale to something like 0.01. The project templates that are available from the editor should already have reasonable values. How did you create your project?

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate the movement tutorial to learn the basics and how to code it.

Comment: Ok, and is it still sluggish after you changed the physics scale?